# Under what condition can a smooth map be factored through the Gauss normal map

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, surfaces

Inspired by this question entitled [When does the shape operator commute with a derivative?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452278/when-does-the-shape-operator-commute-with-a-derivative) we ask the following question:

Assume that $S,H$ are two surfaces whose corresponding Gauss maps are denoted by $n_S:S\to S^2, n_H:H\to  S^2$ respectively.

Let $\phi:S\to H$ be a smooth map.

> Under what conditions there exist a  smooth map $\psi:S^2 \to S^2 $  with $n_H\circ \phi=\psi \circ n_S$ namely the following diagram commute:

$\require{AMScd}$\begin{CD}
S @>\phi>> H\\
@V n_S V V @VV n_{H} V\\
S^2 @>>\psi> S^2
\end{CD}

Please compare the above diagram with the diagram in the above linked question. Are these two questions somehow equivalent?

Comment: Certainly they are not equivalent. In the linked question it is about pointwise behavior, and here you are asking about a global problem.

Comment: @WillieWong  Can one find a possible reation between these two questions?

Comment: Not really. The best you can hope for is that an example satisfying your diagram will also satisfy the diagram in the linked question. But let $S$ be the unit sphere and $H$ be the sphere of radius 2, and $\phi$ be the obvious map. Then $\psi$ is the identity map. Taking the first jet of your diagram gives $$ \begin{CD}
T_pS @>D\phi_p>> T_{\phi(p)}H\\
@V Dn_S V V @VV Dn_{H} V\\
T_pS^2 @>>\mathbf{Id}> T_pS^2
\end{CD}$$ But $D\phi_p = 2 \mathbf{Id}$ so the diagram in the linked question doesn't work.

Comment: In fact, if $S$ and $H$ are the smooth boundaries of two compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then the Gauss maps are smoothly invertible and your diagram can be formed. But for the linked question's diagram to hold, you need $S$ and $H$ to have the same second fundamental forms, and this won't hold for generic $S$ and $H$.

Comment: @WillieWong Yes I see thanks.

Comment: @WillieWong the example you given is very interesting. it is an example of affirmative answer to my post. in this example $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism and Gauss maps are also diffeomorphism so the map $\psi$ is detrtmined uniquely. so I wonder if thete are some complicated example for example degrere of $\phi$ is 2 or >2? for Riemann surfaces embeded on space with holomorphic Gauss maps can we provid a holomorphic $\psi$ when $\phi $ is holomorphic?